# Размер Qscene в зависимости от размера пикселя

Tags: c++, qt

Я размещаю изображения на QScene и затем сохраняю сам QScene как изображение. Мне необходимо, чтобы размер этого изображения соответствовал размеру листа формата А4. Если я правильно понимаю, то в зависимости от монитора, размер сцены в пикселях необходимо задавать разный, т.к имеют место быть разные размеры пикселя. В таком случае необходимо считать каждый раз размер пикселя и на основании этого задавать размер сцены? или это можно сделать как-то иначе?

Answer (score 1):

Вся `QGraphicsScene` умеет масштабироваться, это раз.

Размер пиксела программно узнать невозможно - в EDID может храниться любая ерунда.

Comment: Я не очень понял. Вы имеете в виду, что никак нельзя в таком случае контролировать размер сцены, чтобы он был равен, условно, размеру листа А4?

Comment: @jesuscrew77 да. Вы не знаете, сколько пикселей в дюйме на подключенном мониторе. И узнать не сможете. Только если пользователь сам померяет экран.

Comment: спасибо. и ещё один вопрос. если я размещаю несколько изображений формата `QImage::Format_Mono` на сцене, а потом сохраняю саму сцену как изображение такого же формата,  то качество этих изображений останется прежним, уже будучи в таком виде?

Comment: @jesuscrew77 зависит от способа и формата сохранения

Comment: сохранять хочу в формат .tiff или .raw, что касается способа, то, если Вас не затруднит, подскажите, как сохранять, чтобы качество осталось прежним?

Comment: @jesuscrew77 В данном вопросе это будет оффтопиком - оформляйте новый

Comment: Создал новый вопрос

Answer (score -1):

Размеры А4 - 210мм x 297мм.
Я рассчитывал таким образом:

```
#include <QScreen>
float pixelPerMm = QApplication::screens().at(0)->logicalDotsPerInch()/2.54/10;
float widthA4 = pixelPerMm*210;//Ширина
float widthA4 = pixelPerMm*297;//Высота
```

Берётся логическое DPI основного монитора, и т.к. разрешение это кол-во пикселей на дюйм, а дюйм это 2,54 см, то делаем перевод в см и далее перевод в мм и получаем пикселей на мм.

Comment: Если бы это DPI имело отношение к реальности - цены бы ему не было. Оно настраивается юзером в панели управления Форточкой.

Comment: @gbg Ну есть ещё получение физического дипиая, метод physicalDotsPerInch, но опять же, минуснуть можно всегда, а есть ли у ВАС рабочий вариант?

Comment: рабочего варианта нет - монитор не информирует видеокарту о размере своего пикселя через EDID.

Comment: @gbg, при желании, можно тащить из реестра данные о мониторе, но вопрос зачем? в скурпулёзной точности я не виду смысла, и мой вариант вполне рабочий.